# Titanfall 2/Apex Legends Stop Refreshing Screen After Clicking Out of it

Tags: technical-issues, apex-legends, titanfall-2

Whenever playing these two games, occasionally a pop-up will open up and it will prioritize that over the game and show that. I will then click back into my game, get into a safe spot, then click out to deal with whatever popped up. It also happens when I change it from windowed to fullscreen, as it often opens in windowed

After I have done that though, the game will stop updating the picture (sound still works, button inputs are registered, and I can hear my mouse moving around over menu buttons) after a few seconds. The only way to get it to resume is to click out and back in again, but a few seconds later it freezes the image again.

I run the game in fullscreen with two monitors, and I was wondering if there is any way to prevent this without changing those two things, as the only way to fix it is to quit and restart the game.

Comment: Any screenshot of what the popup says? Such things mostly indicate that something with the graphics (or sometimes, with the sound) setup is wrong and frequently result in crashing of the game. Therefore it would be useful to know the message and take action accordingly.

Comment: You're in full screen mode but you can click out? How can you move the mouse cursor outside of the screen when the game is capturing it? Can you just Alt-Tab instead?

Comment: What OS are you on?

Comment: @DrFish Its not any specific popup. twice it was an achevment, and once it was my  audio maniger dececting my headphones popping out and back in agian.

Comment: @Smock I have two monitors so I just click on my other monitor. I don't use alt-tab since I have it disabled in games.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf I am on Windows 10, with everything up to date.

Comment: Can you run your games in Borderless Window mode?

Comment: Have you tried any Focus Assist modes?

Comment: @DrFish No I have not. I did not even know they were a thing. I will give it a try.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Niether game has that option.

Comment: @DrFish It turns out I had had that on, and things were still getting through.

Comment: What GPU and driver version are you using?

Comment: @Varaquilex I have a Radion RX 580 on driver version 19.12.3

Comment: @K00lman Have you tried turning off the Radeon Enhanced Sync in the game's profile from Radeon Settings?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated by @Varaquilex in there comment, I turned off Radeon Enhanced Sync. This stopped the game from freezing when the game opened in full-screen.